# Saving image from URL using Picasso without change in size (using bitmap.compress() changes size)

Tags: android, image-processing, picasso

I am using Picasso for my image handling and use it to download images from a backend server and save to the local device. I use `Target` to save the image

```
            Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .into(target);
```

Since the target code gets a bitmap, I have to use `bitmap.compress()` to write the image to local disk and I use JPEF format with quality of 100 assuming this will preserve the original quality.

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202248/bitmap-compressed-with-quality-100-bigger-file-size-than-original) it seems like this might not be what I want. In one case, the image on the backend was 90kb and the image that was written was 370kb. The original image can be generated using an arbitrary quality value. What is the easiest way to save the image using Picasso without the size/quality changing?

```
     Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom arg1) {

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        try {
                            out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                            out.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                            
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void info) {
                    }
                }.execute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
            }
        };
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

UPDATE: more elegant solution here: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1025#issuecomment-102661647

Solved the problem using this solution.

In my `PagerAdapter`'s `instantiateItem()` method, I run an `AsyncTask` that will download the image, save it to a file and then call Picasso with that image file.

PagerAdapter instantiateItem():

```
        RemoteImageToImageViewAsyncTask remoteImageToImageViewAsyncTask =
                new RemoteImageToImageViewAsyncTask(imageView, url, imagePath);
        remoteImageToImageViewAsyncTask.execute();
```

RemoteImageToImageViewAsyncTask

```
public class RemoteImageToImageViewAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ImageView imageView;
    String url;
    File output;

    public RemoteImageToImageViewAsyncTask(ImageView imageView, String url, File output) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.url = url;
        this.output = output;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Downloads the image from url to output
        ImageDownloader.download(url, output);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                   .load(output)
                   .into(imageView);
    }
}
```